# Mathematica refuses to simplify units

Tags: simplifying-expressions, units

Here is a minimal example:

```
Quantity[z, "m"]/(Quantity[x, "m"] Log[q] + Quantity[y, "m"])
```

where `z,x,q,y` are undefined variables. Mathematica refuses to cancel the meter unit. I tried `UnitSimplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Simplify`, but they don't work. I think the `Log[q]` term is culprit. If you remove it, the meter goes away.

This is problematic, because I cannot use this expression inside numerical methods. I need to find a way to simplify the units. I can't remove them by hand, because this expression is generated automatically from other routines I have in my code. Any ideas?

Comment: @LouisB That's exactly what my answer below does.

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue is that Mathematica doesn't know the dimensions of `Log[q]`. You could tell Mathematica that it is dimensionless by using the unit "PureUnities". So:

```
Quantity[z, "m"]/(Quantity[x, "m"] Quantity[Log[q], "PureUnities"] + Quantity[y, "m"])
```

> z/(y + x*Log[q])

Comment: Is "PureUnities" the same as "DimensionlessUnit"?  I've never heard of it.

Comment: By the way, I'm asking because this occurred to me as well but I assumed the OP would want to assign a unit (or, rather, no unit) to q instead of Log[q].  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't what you were hoping for, but I'll offer it up anyway (and apologies in advance for my awkward use of patterns):

```
Quantity[z, 
  "m"]/(Quantity[x, "m"] Log[q] + Quantity[y, "m"]) //. {Times[
    a_?(! QuantityQ[#] &), b_?QuantityQ] -> 
   Quantity[a QuantityMagnitude[b], QuantityUnit[b]]}
```

will yield the answer you expect:

```
z/(y + x Log[q])
```

Comment: That rule simply replaces quantitities with their magnitude. What if I am summing meters to centimeters? This will miss a factor of 100.

Comment: @becko That's incorrect--try it and you'll see.  All the rule does is look for terms which multiply a Quantity by something which isn't a Quantity and replaces it with a single Quantity in which the multiplication is performed in the magnitude of the Quantity.  The units are preserved.

Comment: You are totally correct, my bad. I should have tested before commenting.